# Is there a need to use read_html in rvest before scraping an html page?

Tags: r, rvest

I am using rvest to scrape web pages.
I used to open a session with the url and call directly functions such as `html_node()`.

I noticed that most of the examples I see proceed with reading the page before analysing its content.
I tested both options and measured the system elapsed time and have seen no significant difference.
Can anyone advise if there is really a need to read in advance the entire page with `read_html()`?

here is a sample test

```
library(rvest)
url="https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html"
sess=html_session(url )
system.time(html_nodes(sess,"div"))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.02    0.00    0.02 
> system.time(html_nodes(read_html(sess),"div"))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.02    0.00    0.02
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, your two calls are equivalent. `html_nodes` with a url as the first argument is just calling `html_nodes` on `read_html(url)`, as you can see. Your first call uses `html_nodes.default` and you second call `html_nodes.session`.

```
> getFromNamespace("html_nodes.session","rvest")

function (x, css, xpath) 
{
    html_nodes(xml2::read_html(x), css, xpath)
}
<environment: namespace:rvest>
```

The main reason I would still prefer `read_html` is that I have often have several operation to perform on a page (read some nodes, then some other nodes and compile all infos). Using `read_html` once in order to perform multiple html_nodes will be faster in the long run.

```
library(rvest)

url="https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html"
sess=html_session(url )

no_read <- function(sess){
  html_nodes(sess,"div")
  html_nodes(sess,"p")
}

do_read <- function(sess) {
  p <- read_html(sess)
  html_nodes(p,"div")
  html_nodes(p,"p")
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(no_read(sess),do_read(sess))
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 no_read(sess) 41.42506 44.06154 55.05718 46.62327 66.03544 190.4596   100
 do_read(sess) 28.71807 31.33751 42.38105 33.21593 47.32962 240.6938   100
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. I doubted this would make a difference if you make many calls on the page but my question is due to the fact that the session data structure was not very clear for me, and I suspected it might already contains the entire information of the page.